# How to compile-time condition on template typename?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Suppose I have a `class A` template as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    T data;
public:
    void func(){} //concerned function ** see here **
};
```

Now I have another `class B` template, say as

```
template<typename U>
class B
{
    // ... something whatever
};
```

That means the condition for not constructing the function is that the immediate template `typename T` is `B`. And `C` can be any type including `A` and `B`.

Comment: You can partially specialize `A`: `template<class C> class A<B<C> > { B<C> data; /* no func() */ };`  Whether that solution is practical depends on how much other stuff is in `A`, though

Comment: `class A` is a real heavy class which is not feasible to duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

1. Member functions of class templates aren't generated unless they are odr-used. This is part of the mechanism's strength.
2. If you want to constrain the use of this member function, then you would indeed use `std::is_same`. The trick is to define the appropriate trait/meta-function:

   ```
   template<class, template<class...> class>
   struct is_template_instance : std::false_type {};

   template<template<class...> class T, class... Cs>
   struct is_template_instance<T<Cs...>, T> : std::true_type {};
   ```

   The true specialization will only be chosen for something like `is_template_instance<std::vector<int>, std::vector>`. Now just put it to use, either static assert or `std::enable_if`:

   ```
   auto func() ->
     typename std::enable_if<!is_template_instance<T, B>::value>::type {
   }
   ```

Comment: @StoryTeller Your type trait looks wrong to me. `T` is always a type, so it will always take the `std::false_type` branch I think.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - T is not a type, T is a template. Or are you referring to the OP's code? The `T` in the trait is different to the `T` in the OP.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, `T` from OP. It is a template which expects a type, yes. But then how can it ever match the second `is_template_instance`? It doesn't take any template parameters.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - T is a stand-in for a template that accepts any number of types. The `Cs...` are those types. `T<Cs...>` is a type also. It is more specialized than the base template. You can read the standard or try it out.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - As for the OP. When `T = B<C>` it will instantiate `is_template_instance<B<C>, B>`. The true specialization.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I tried my best to follow your answer and implement it [here](http://cpp.sh/3ed6x). If you don't mind, could you kindly help me where to  put the things in this minimal case.

Comment: @ffslq - (1). You specified `void` as the return type, not `enable_if<>::type`. (2) The condition should be reversed according to your example (I misread you OP and will update the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to [partial specialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) the template:

```
template<typename C>
class A<B<C>> // Used when A<B<C>> is instantiated
{
    B<C> data;
};
```

The only downside on this is that this requires some code duplication, which is not always possible.

Instead, you can create a base class with all the functionality, and derived from that base:

```
// Base class with all the common functionality.
template<typename T>
class A_impl
{
protected:
    T data;
};

// Special case when 'func' is available.
template<typename T>
class A : public A_impl<T>
{
public:
    void func() {}
};

// Another special case where 'func' is not available.
template<typename C>
class A<B<C>> : public A_impl<B<C>> {
};
```